# Android Recyclerview- increase font size of all inner textviews

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

this code is in my MainActivity(working good) :

```
mAdapter = new Adapter_RecyclerViewReader(readerLineObjs);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller(getBaseContext()));
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

and the recyclerview Adapter:

```
public class Adapter_RecyclerViewReader extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_RecyclerViewReader.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<ReaderLineObj> readerLineObjList;
    float minTextSize = 50;
    float maxTextSize = 80;
    Adapter_RecyclerViewReader.MyViewHolder holderGlobal;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvRowHidId, tvRowTitle, tvRowContent;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            tvRowTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvRowTitle);
            tvRowContent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvRowContent);

        }


    }

    public void ResizeTextSize(Boolean makeBigger){


    }

    public Adapter_RecyclerViewReader(List<ReaderLineObj> readerLineObjList) {
        this.readerLineObjList = readerLineObjList;
    }


    @Override
    public Adapter_RecyclerViewReader.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_recycler_list_reader, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Adapter_RecyclerViewReader.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ReaderLineObj readerLineObj = readerLineObjList.get(position);

        if (readerLineObj.getTitle().length() >0 ){
            holder.tvRowTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(readerLineObj.getTitle()));
        }else{
            holder.tvRowTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        holder.tvRowContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(readerLineObj.getContent()));




    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return readerLineObjList.size();
    }
}
```

the font size of tvRowTitle and tvRowContentare the same btw.

I'v added 2 Buttons in the MainActivity xml, and i want them to have functinalty 
of getting current fontsize of tvRowTitle and then increase/decrease it (Relatively for current fontsize) for all textviews in the recyclerview.

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kry87.jpg)

clicing the left button will add 1sp to current font size all over the grid view title & content.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Points to note:
i) You will be changing value in the Activity class but adapter has to implement the changes you make on the sizes
ii) You will need to reload the views using

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

method

So what is the work around. You can have a static float value to hold the size, for example, in the MainAcitivity initialized.

```
static float size_of_items;
```

then on increment button change the values of float as

```
size_of_items=size_of_items+1;
```

do similar thing on the decrement button.

NOTE: On the adapter class make this changes to the onBindViewHolder method adding

```
holder.tvRowTitle.setTextSize(TypeValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, MainActivity.size_of_items);
holder.tvRowContent.setTextSize(TypeValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, MainActivity.size_of_items);
```

so that you have your code inside onBindViewHolder as below

```
      if (readerLineObj.getTitle().length() >0 ){
            holder.tvRowTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(readerLineObj.getTitle()));
        }else{
            holder.tvRowTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        holder.tvRowContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(readerLineObj.getContent()));
holder.tvRowTitle.setTextSize(TypeValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, MainActivity.size_of_items);
    holder.tvRowContent.setTextSize(TypeValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, MainActivity.size_of_items);
```

FINALLY:
Remember to use the `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`after every change in `size_of_items` so you have such a simple method:

```
private void increaseTextSize(){
size_of_items=size_of_items+1;
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

All the best, hoping not too late with the answer. You do not need the method i created last, instead you can use the code inside on your increase_size button on the setOnClickListener method. Goodluck